# Breaking loop issue in python

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I've already hit an obstacle.

I am trying to write a code for Pig Latin converter and I am using function to write it. And I run in in while loop.

I tried to figure out how to end the loop by using break but it just won't end and only by the second time I input, it works.

I want to find out what I am doing wrong and if you guys could help me out, I would be really grateful. Thank you :)

```
    pig = 'ay'

    def func(): 
        word = input('Hello. Please Enter your First Word:').lower()


        if len(word) > 0 and word.isalpha():
            first = word[0]
            if first in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
                print('The first letter must begin with a consonant. Would you like to try a different word? (Y/N)') and inpup().lower()
                if input() == 'y':
                    return func()
                else:
                    print("Thank you for using Pig Latin Converter")
                    return False



        else:
            new_word = word[1].upper() + word[2:] + ' ' + first.upper() + pig
            print(new_word)
            print("Would you like to try a different word? (Y/N)") and input().lower()
            if input() == 'y':
                return func()
            else:
                print("Thank you for using Pig Latin Converter")
                return False



while True:
    func()

    if False:
        break
```

Comment: `if func(): break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    func()

    if False:
        break
```

func() returns a value True, but it is not assigned to anything. The while statement will still be True, and proceed to loop forever. Change it to something like this

```
proceed = True
while proceed:
    proceed = func()
```

This time the loop runs the first time as proceed is true, executes func() then depending on the return value of func() - either True or False the body will either repeat or finish. Note you need to change the retrun value if the code executes to True, eg..

```
if input() == 'y':
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. It solved it! I am so happy.

Comment: Could this not be simplified to `while func(): pass`, or would that be unpythonic?

Comment: Yes, you could.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, here's a cleaned version of your function. You can run your converter just by calling it, no need for a while loop as your function is recursive already.

```
def func(): 
    pig = 'ay' # Moved this inside as there was no need for it to be defined out of the function's scope.
    word = input('Hello. Please Enter a Word:').lower() # Changed this so it doesn't say 'First' everytime


    if not (len(word) > 0 and word.isalpha()):
        # If you end up in here then the user entered something incorrectly, So we should tell them that. 
        print('The word needs to contain alphabetic characters only. Would you like to try again? (Y/N)') and inpup().lower()
        if input() == 'y':
            # Note that your function is recursive, so you don't need to have a while loop.  
            return func()
        else:
            print("Thank you for using Pig Latin Converter")
            return False
    first = word[0]
    if first in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        print('The first letter must begin with a consonant. Would you like to try a different word? (Y/N)') and inpup().lower()
        if input() == 'y':
            return func()
        else:
            print("Thank you for using Pig Latin Converter")
            return False



    else:
        # I had to replace the 'first' variable with 'word[0]'. This is because if the user entered a valid string then you would never assign the first variable.
        new_word = word[1].upper() + word[2:] + ' ' + word[0].upper() + pig
        print(new_word)
        print("Would you like to try a different word? (Y/N)") and input().lower()
        if input() == 'y':
            return func()
        else:
            print("Thank you for using Pig Latin Converter")
            return False
func()
```

IF you run this it should work :-) I've put comments everywhere I changed something.

Comment: If you are not returning the value to a variable the return False is redundant, it should just be return.